# trying to export products give 500 internal server error

Tags: magento-1.7, product, importexport

Trying to export All products but it gives me 500 Internal server error. i have set max execution time and max input time to 9000 also input memory 256MB on my cpanel and htaccess file. everything is fine from some post i see directory permissions are also correct and on another post i try change if condition in product.php but still problem is same please any one who faced and solved suggest me thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to increase below

```
php_value memory_limit 256M  to  php_value memory_limit 1024m
php_value max_execution_time 18000 to php_value max_execution_time 36000
```

in .htaccess file.May be it help.

Comment: but my hosting give me maximum 512 which is also not work

Comment: How much sku's you trying to export?

Comment: 10057 are total sku i want to export

Comment: There are so may sku,you can't export in 512 mb memory_limit.You need to write custom script for this.

Comment: could you please help any hint for script sample script

Comment: Go to this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869118/how-to-export-product-csv-with-full-url-of-product

Comment: did this work with magento 1.7.0.2?

Comment: Yes ,this is working but before going to run script please take backup of Database.

Comment: @ akgola  : am increased what u suggested, bit not working, am using magento 1.9.2.3, could u help me >>>

Comment: Completely not working

Answer (score -2):

Open the file at

```
app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php
```

line: 873

Find the code

```
$dataRow += $stockItemRows[$productId];
```

In order to update the code to:

```
$dataRow = array_merge($dataRow,$stockItemRows[$productId]);
```

Comment: Don't edit core modules. You'll be in a world of hurt when you update Magento or install some 3rd party modules that depend on it. Use rewrites or copy the class to your `local` codePool.